# Discontinous and differentiable

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

If we have a two functions

$f:[-1/2, 2] \to \mathbb{R}$

$g: [-1/2,2] \to \mathbb{R}$

$f(x) = [x^2-3]$   where $[ \cdot ]$ denotes greatest integer

$g(x) = |x| f(x) + |4x-7| f(x)$

Now we have to comment on number of points where $f(x)$ is discontinuous and number of points where $g(x)$ is not differentiable.

I tried and got the result of points of discontinuity using graph, i.e. $4$ points.

But now I got stuck how to proceed. To find the points for non-differentiability.

My try is on :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrvV4.jpg

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig sorry for that mistake